Surface area of punched piece of metal piping
A cylindrical steel pipe of infinitesimal thickness with radius
$4\,\mathrm{cm}$ gets a hole of equal radius punched through the upper part
($z \geq 0$) such that the projection onto the $xy$-plane of the missing piece is given by the
circular disc $D = \{(x,y)\mid x^{2}+ y^{2} \leq 16\}$. The projection onto the
$xz$-plane is the wedge given by $z = \lvert x \rvert$ for
$\lvert x\rvert,\lvert y \rvert\leq 4$.
Find the area of the punched off piece of steel.
Now I would imagine that solving this would be as easy as finding some graph
$z = f(x, y)$ and then parameterize it and compute the surface integral over
the circular disc $D$. However every attempt has given me an answer that
contradicts the solutions manual.
The graph for the upper part of the half pipe is given by
$z = \sqrt{16-y^{2}}$ over the region $D$. The "trivial" parametrization
$\mathbf{r}(s,t) = (s, t, \sqrt{16-t^{2}})$ for
$\rvert s\lvert, \rvert t\lvert \leq 4$ yields partials
$\mathbf{r}_{s}(s,t) = (1, 0, 0)$ and $\mathbf{r}_{t}(s,t) = (0, 1, -t/\sqrt{16-t^{2}})$
so that $\mathbf{r}_{s} \times \mathbf{r}_{t} = (0, t/\sqrt{16-t^{2}}, 1)$.
Now setting up the integral
\begin{gather*}
      A = \iint\limits_{D}\lvert\mathbf{r}_{s} \times \mathbf{r}_{t}\rvert\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}s\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}t =
      \iint\limits_{D}\sqrt{\frac{t^{2}}{16-t^{2}} + 1}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}s\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}t =\\
      = 4\iint\limits_{D}\frac{1}{\sqrt{16-t^{2}}}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}s \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}t =
      4\int_{-4}^{4}\int_{-4}^{4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{16-t^{2}}}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}s \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}t=\\
      = 32\int_{-4}^{4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{16-t^{2}}}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}t = 32\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}t
\end{gather*}
setting $u(t) = \arcsin t$ gives $u'(t) = 1/\sqrt{1-t^{2}}$ so that
\begin{gather*}
  32\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}t =
  32 \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}u = 32\pi\,\mathrm{cm^{2}}.
\end{gather*}
However the solutions manual states that the surface area ought to be
$64\,\mathrm{cm^{2}}$. I've also tried different parametrizations yielding
the same result that I got. Where is my mistake?

You did not set up the limits on the double integral correctly. You integrated over a square, rather than over a disk. Let's use polar coordinates:
\begin{align*}
\text{Surface area}&=4\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^4 \frac1{\sqrt{16-r^2\sin^2\theta}}r\,dr\,d\theta \\
&= 16\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac4{\sin^2\theta}(1-\cos\theta)\,d\theta = 64(\csc \theta-\cot \theta)\Big]_0^{\pi/2} = 64.
\end{align*}
Note that the improper integral converges at $0$, as $\lim\limits_{\theta\to 0}\dfrac{1-\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta} = \dfrac12$, and $\lim\limits_{\theta\to 0} \csc\theta-\cot\theta=0$.
It's far easier do it (correctly) in cartesian coordinates, particularly if you choose the right order of integration. You have
$$16\int_0^4\int_0^{\sqrt{16-y^2}} \frac1{\sqrt{16-y^2}}\,dx\,dy = 
16\int_0^4 dy = 64.$$

Refer to the diagram below.

We can see that the cutout must have a surface area $S$ less than the lateral area of the upper half of the cylinder from $x = -4$ to $x = 4$; i.e.,
$$S < (4+4)\cdot 4 \pi = 32 \pi.$$
So your answer cannot possibly be correct as it is too large.
Presently, I don't have the time to examine your work in detail, but I would like to suggest an alternate approach to computing the desired area that relies on the fact that the cylinder is a ruled surface.  What I would suggest is to parametrize the cutout by two values:  an angle $\theta \in [0,\pi]$ that captures the angle of a point on the circular $yz$-cross section of the cylinder relative to the origin, specifically $$(x,y,z) = (0, 4 \cos \theta, 4 \sin \theta),$$ and a width parameter $w$ that represents the distance between the two red curves of intersection along the length of the cylinder at the angle $\theta$.
I leave it as an exercise to show that these red curves are ellipses, to find the equation of these ellipses parametrized by $\theta$, and then to compute $w$ as a function of $\theta$.  Then because the surface is ruled, the surface area $S$ is simply the integral
$$S = \int_{\theta = 0}^\pi w(\theta) \, d\theta.$$

Could you please tell what software you used for the visualisation?

@SohamSaha The image was created using Mathematica version 14.
